# MX record changes made in Godaddy account not accepted by Google Apps

Tags: g-suite, godaddy, mx-record

I have a linux deluxe hosting account on godaddy.com and I can host multiple websites on that account. Not all the websites are .com and I've bought the domain names from different registrars (just changing the name servers in order to host that domain name on godaddy).

Now, I wish to use google apps for one of my hosted sites and I have to change the MX record on gogaddy with google servers name ([as in this tutorial](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=140034)). The problem is that google apps doesn't take the changes. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to wait until the TTL on your MX records expires.  That is typically 1-8 hours.

Answer (score 1):

Was it Google Apps which didn't take the change, or GoDaddy?

I just went through this the other night, with GoDaddy. GoDaddy took the MX record changes without issue, but it took Google several hours before it recognized that the process was complete and it was willing to send & receive e-mail on my behalf.

Were you able to verify ownership of the domain to Google? Recall that this is one of the first steps they ask you to take. If you have file-level access to the webroots for the domain names, that process is relatively painless.

Comment: yes, i did the first step without problems. the problem is that i have multiple sites hosted on godaddy. What means host @ on MX godaddy control panel?

Comment: Each domain will have different MX records. You'll be entering *exactly* the information Google gives you -- the @ for host, the server names (make sure the trailing `.` is in there) and the TTL (which for me was 1 week). Do all this correctly, wait for your TTL to lapse, and Google should start sending & receiving e-mail for you.

Answer (score 1):

Hey Godaddy is removing the trailing '.' automatically, it really frustrated me.  Irfan